Squid included in 22.04 is v5 - latest is v6 - what about security fixes?
I'm looking for "official" documentation. If a vulnerability happens in Squid v5 or v6, will ubuntu deliver a fix for it in v5? Since no more development is done on v5? (or ubuntu 20.04 with Squid v4).
Basically my company wants "latest" version of software, Squid v5 is not latest, I'm looking for documentation to say "it's still ok". Or not.

Does this answer your question? Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?

If you look at the change log of the squid version 5.7 in Ubuntu 22.04 you will see the squid vulnerability discovered in 2024, CVE-2024-23638 was patched.

Security fixes are backported to the released products via SRU... The package version is only upgraded IF it's less work than backporting fixes alone (including testing for each, but notifications need to be sent out if a newer version is done which is extremely rare - how many of those do you actually recall?  I vaguely recall about two last ~decade, as updating versions of software on a stable release system is a ton of work)
